# Use a Loop or Apply to Overwrite Only Certain Values of a Variable in a Data Frame Based on a Condition

Tags: r, loops, apply

I would like to write a loop or apply in `R` to overwrite only certain values of a variable based on a condition. Here is an example data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(
  state = c("MA","CO","TX"),
  random_numeric = c(26,28,4),
  var1 = c(3,0,0),
  var2 = c(3,1,5),
  var3 = c(0,1,0),
  prelim_row_sum = c(6,2,5)
)
df
  state random_numeric var1 var2 var3 prelim_row_sum
1    MA             26    3    3    0              6
2    CO             28    0    1    1              2
3    TX              4    0    5    0              5
```

In `df`, I would like to replace **only** the *first value* in `var1`, `var2`, or `var3` to zero if it equals half `prelim_row_sum`. Thus, a correct loop or apply would replace only the first three and first 1 to zero.  I have the `random_numeric` and `state` variables in the example data frame to show that there other character and numeric variables in my larger data frame. Accordingly, a `dplyr` solution with `across` would not work for me. I could, of course, do this one-by-one:

```
df[1,3] <- 0
df[2,4] <- 0
df$final_row_sum = rowSums(df[3:5])
df
  state random_numeric var1 var2 var3 prelim_row_sum final_row_sum
1    MA             26    0    3    0              6             3
2    CO             28    0    0    1              2             1
3    TX              4    0    5    0              5             5
```

But I would really appreciate help with a loop, apply, or a function, so that I can do this on larger, non-stylized data frames. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do with with `apply`. I allowed for a little bit of generality in that you must input which columns to apply this function to. At the end there is a wrapper function so you can set those values to zero and then create the `final_row_sum` column.

```
  state = c("MA","CO","TX"),
  random_numeric = c(26,28,4),
  var1 = c(3,0,0),
  var2 = c(3,1,5),
  var3 = c(0,1,0),
  prelim_row_sum = c(6,2,5)
)

my_func <- function(x){
  value_to_zero <- which(
    x[1:(length(x)-1)] == (x[length(x)]/2)
  )
  if(length(value_to_zero) > 0){
    x[value_to_zero[1]] <- 0
  }
  return(x)
}

new_df <- df

cols_to_fix <- c("var1", "var2", "var3", "prelim_row_sum")

new_df[,cols_to_fix] <- t(
  apply(
    new_df[,cols_to_fix],
    1,
    my_func
  )
)

new_df$final_row_sum <- rowSums(new_df[,cols_to_fix[-length(cols_to_fix)]])

new_df

  state random_numeric var1 var2 var3 prelim_row_sum final_row_sum
1    MA             26    0    3    0              6             3
2    CO             28    0    0    1              2             1
3    TX              4    0    5    0              5             5

all_in_one <- function(x, cols){
  
  my_func <- function(x){
    value_to_zero <- which(
      x[1:(length(x)-1)] == (x[length(x)]/2)
    )
    if(length(value_to_zero) > 0){
      x[value_to_zero[1]] <- 0
    }
    return(x)
  }
  
  
  x[,cols] <- t(
    apply(
      x[,cols],
      1,
      my_func
    )
  )
  
  x$final_row_sum <- rowSums(x[,cols[-length(cols)]])
  
  return(x)
  
}

answer <- all_in_one(df, c("var1", "var2", "var3", "prelim_row_sum"))

  state random_numeric var1 var2 var3 prelim_row_sum final_row_sum
1    MA             26    0    3    0              6             3
2    CO             28    0    0    1              2             1
3    TX              4    0    5    0              5             5
```

Comment: I accepted this answer because it was the most general of the three. The only thing I had to change was the last line for implementing something more generally. Great answer! Thank you @mfidino

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
cbind(df[1:2], t(apply(df[-(1:2)], 1, function(x){
  x[which.max(x == x[4]/2)] <- 0
  c(x, final_row_sum = sum(x[-4]))
})))

#   state random_numeric var1 var2 var3 prelim_row_sum final_row_sum
# 1    MA             26    0    3    0              6             3
# 2    CO             28    0    0    1              2             1
# 3    TX              4    0    5    0              5             5
```

Comment: thank you for your incredible answer! Could I kindly ask you to walk me through the answer? I just want to make sure I can correctly apply it to my data frame with 20 variables. I am a highly proficient `R` user, but you are clearly at another level. Thank you in advance for your consideration.

Comment: EDIT: Actually, for some reason, the final_row_sum for TX was giving me 10 instead of 5. Not sure what is happening there...

Comment: @Mike thanks for your reply! I use your reproducible data and my code, which gives 5 for `final_row_sum` of `TX`. Maybe you choose wrong columns to put into `apply()`. `df[-(1:2)]` is only for your example data, not for real one.

Comment: I ran your code again, and it worked perfectly. I don't know what happened earlier. In any case, please accept my apologies for the mishap, and thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

I have a more function based, tidyverse answer. It will return a data frame of var1, var2, and var3. You can easily combine that with the origin data frame. I like the origin Tsai's response, but I think this is a bit easily to understand and is more flexible.

```r
library(tidyvese)  # you really just need purrr
f <- function(var1, var2, var3, prelim_row_sum, ...) {
    cols <- c(var1, var2, var3)
    index <- which((cols * 2) == prelim_row_sum)[1]
    assign(paste0("var", index), 0)
    data.frame(var1=var1, var2=var2, var3=var3)
}

pmap_dfr(df, f)
```

Comment: Good idea! I think it's a little comprehensive to call your method a `tidyverse` answer because you only use `pmap()` of `purrr`.

Comment: True, I only used `pmap`, but  I was trying to point out the stylistic difference between our solutions.

Comment: Yeah I didn't remark on your answer. I just suggest that the term you use might not be precise enough. We say `tidyverse` answer only when multiple functions in the `tidyverse` framework are used.